# functions for checkboxes in Javascript

Tags: javascript, checkbox

So I have a code with check boxes and I need a suggestion for a function to get data from database if the check box is checked. The table name for the database is Shifliigid and the column name which data I use in the check box is shiffer. So any suggestions would be nice (English isn't my first or even second language, so don't be mad for the short and shady explanation)

```
var nodeTr = document.createElement("tr");
var td_tekst = document.createElement("td");
td_tekst.innerHTML="Motoorika";
var td = document.createElement("td");
td.style.width = "370px";
var input = document.createElement("textarea");
//input.type = "text";
input.name = "//funktsioonide hindamine/funktsioon[" + count + "]/motoorika";
input.value = rowData.motoorika.replace(/<br\/>/g, "\r\n");
input.className = "txt_left";
input.style.width = "368px";
input.style.fontSize = "9pt";
var nodeMotoorika = input;
addChangeListener(input);
td.appendChild(input);
nodeTr.appendChild(td_tekst);
nodeTr.appendChild(td);
evaluationContainer.appendChild(nodeTr);

//This is the part that makes the checkboxes

var nodeTr = document.createElement("tr");
var td_tekst = document.createElement("td");
var td = document.createElement("td");
var echeckbox = document.createElement("input");
echeckbox.type="checkbox";
echeckbox.name = "//funktsioonide hindamine/funktsioon[" + count + "]/nagemine/vahend_0301";
td.appendChild(echeckbox);
td.innerHTML+="käeprotees/-ortoos";
nodeTr.appendChild(td_tekst);
nodeTr.appendChild(td);
evaluationContainer.appendChild(nodeTr);


var nodeTr = document.createElement("tr");
var td_tekst = document.createElement("td");
td_tekst.innerHTML="Liikumine";
var td = document.createElement("td");
td.style.width = "370px";
var input = document.createElement("textarea");
//input.type = "text";
input.name = "//funktsioonide hindamine/funktsioon[" + count + "]/liikumine";
input.value = rowData.liikumine.replace(/<br\/>/g, "\r\n");
input.className = "txt_left";
input.style.width = "368px";
input.style.fontSize = "9pt";
var nodeLiikumine = input;
addChangeListener(input);
td.appendChild(input);

nodeTr.appendChild(td_tekst);
nodeTr.appendChild(td);
evaluationContainer.appendChild(nodeTr);


//This is the part that makes the checkboxes

var nodeTr = document.createElement("tr");
var td_tekst = document.createElement("td");
var td = document.createElement("td");
var echeckbox = document.createElement("input");
echeckbox.type="checkbox";
echeckbox.name = "//funktsioonide hindamine/funktsioon[" + count + "]/nagemine/vahend_0302";
td.appendChild(echeckbox);
td.innerHTML+="jalaprotees/-ortoos";
nodeTr.appendChild(td_tekst);
nodeTr.appendChild(td);
evaluationContainer.appendChild(nodeTr);
```

Comment: budy i dont know which lang is this... but usually when the checkbox is checked only that value is posted on the server side...               it you want multiple values u have to specify checkbox name as array example  <input type=checkbox name=ch[] value='ur values'>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no JS "function to get data from database".

You will have to choose a backend technology to access the database.  For example PHP.

Answer (score 0):

Use ajax calls to get the data from database using PHP or asp.
You can check if a particular checkbox is checked using the checked property of DOM.